# ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'libxml-ruby' (>= 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that I copied to my machine. I'm getting following error upon accessing application.

```
    MissingSourceFile (no such file to load -- xml):
    app/controllers/results_controller.rb:6
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
```

I tried installing libxml, getting following error:

```
  [root@localhost log]# gem install libxml-ruby
  WARNING:  RubyGems 1.2+ index not found for:
  RubyGems will revert to legacy indexes degrading performance.
  ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'libxml-ruby' (>= 0) in any repository
  [root@localhost log]#
```

How can this issue be resolved?

The Rails Version: 2.3.8
The Ruby Version:  1.8.7
Operating System: FC18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error implies that the gem sources your user has cannot resolve `libxml-ruby`.  `libxml-ruby` appears to also be hosted by [rubygems.org](https://rubygems.org/gems/libxml-ruby).  So you could add `https://rubygems.org` to your sources and install the gem.

```
# gem sources -a https://rubygems.org
https://rubygems.org added to sources
```

Then install `libxml-ruby`:

```
# gem install libxml-ruby
```

This should successfully install the gem.

In order to see the list of available sources, you can issue `gem sources`:

```
# gem sources
```